# Where is official Microsoft documentation for SP.Utilities.Utility.SendEmail in SharePoint online

Tags: sharepoint-online, documentation

Where is official Microsoft documentation for SP.Utilities.Utility.SendEmail in SharePoint online. 
The old one for SharePoint 2013 is here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj838435.aspx .
But where is actual for SharePoint online? 
Google didn't help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the below link for Sendmail-

[Utility.SendEmail method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.utilities.utility.sendemail.aspx)

For all other methods of SPUtility in SPO , you can use the below link -

[Utility methods](https://msdn.microsoft.com/EN-US/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.utilities.utility_methods.aspx)

Namespace for SPUtility in SPO - [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Utilities namespace](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.utilities.aspx)